# PHP PDO query returns inaccurate value for FLOAT fields

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am guessing this has came up before, but I couldn't find the answer to my question. Here is a little code snippet:

```
    $stmt = $this -> db -> query("
        SELECT
          `Field`
        FROM
          `Table`
        WHERE
          (`ID` = 33608)");
    var_dump($stmt -> fetch());
```

And this is the result I get:

```
    array(1) { ["Field"]=> float(1.7999999523163) }
```

However, the data in the MySQL database is 1.8. The type of the field is float(7,4). $this->db is a PDO object.
I have recently migrated to PDO (from AdoDB), and this code was working fine before. I am not sure what went wrong here. Could you point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce it. Do you pass any particular setting in the PDO constructor?

Comment: The MySQL driver for PDO returns float or string depending on the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` setting, but I still get either `float(18)` or `string(7) "18.0000"` :-?

Comment: This is what I use to initialize PDO (sorry, I don't know how to add a code block here):

            try {
                $pdo = new Db("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME.";charset=utf8", DBUSER, DBPASS);
                $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
                $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                die('DB Error');
            }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [Floating-Point Types (Approximate Value) - `FLOAT`, `DOUBLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/floating-point-types.html):

> MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert `999.00009` into a `FLOAT(7,4)` column, the approximate result is `999.0001`.
>
> Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation dependencies. For more information, see [Section C.5.5.8, “Problems with Floating-Point Values”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/problems-with-float.html)
>
> For maximum portability, code requiring storage of approximate numeric data values should use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE PRECISION` with no specification of precision or number of digits.

Therefore, upon inserting `1.8` into your database, MySQL rounded the literal to `001.8000` and encoded the closest *approximation* to that number in [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) format: i.e. `0x3FE66666`, whose bits signify:

```
Sign           : 0b0

Biased exponent: 0b01111111
               =   127 (representation includes bias of +127, therefore exp = 0)

Significand    : 0b[1.]11001100110011001100110
                    ^ hidden bit, not stored in binary representation
               =   [1.]7999999523162841796875
```

This equates to:

```
 (-1)^0 * 1.7999999523162841796875 * 2^0
=         1.7999999523162841796875
```

This is the value that is returned by MySQL to the client.  It would appear that AdoDB then inspected the column's datatype and rounded the result accordingly, whereas PDO does not.

If you want exact values, you should use a [fixed point datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fixed-point-types.html), such as `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `DECIMAL` field type instead of `FLOAT` if you want accurate values.
And PDO has nothing to do with it. It's rather related to how computers works in general.

Comment: Using `DECIMAL` will have the undesirable side effect that PDO will return the value as `STRING` no matter if you have `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` set to `FALSE` and you are using the proper  `mysqlnd` driver. So, depending on his needs, he's better stuck with `FLOAT`.