# PDO STRINGIFY_FETCHES and float values in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to fetch the correct datatype from mysql with PDO on php. I have a Problem with float values. Even if the column in table is set to FLOAT(10,2), PDO isnt giving me back the correct number of decimals. Is this a PDO bug? I am using Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16 and mysqlnd 5.0.10. Is there any way to get back the correct result which is not something like round($var, 2)?

```
$sDbHost = 'someip';
$sDbUser = 'root';
$sDbPass = '';

$oPdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$sDbHost}", $sDbUser, $sDbPass);
$oPdoConn = $oPdo;
// make PDO use the datatype being returned from mysql
$oPdoConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);
$oPdoConn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

// create a table with a float of lenght 10 and TWO(!) decimalplaces
$oPdoConn->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `paymentClass`.`floatTestTable3` (`testfield` float(10,2) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;");
$oPdoConn->query("INSERT INTO `paymentClass`.`floatTestTable3` VALUES (10.99);");

$oPdoFloatTest = $oPdoConn->query("SELECT * FROM `paymentClass`.`floatTestTable3`");

var_dump($oPdoFloatTest->fetchAll());
```

> // result should be float 10.99
>
> // but result is float 10.989999771118

Comment: Your database just restricts your view to 2dp, but holds the full float value. Your expected result isn't your actual result to 2dp, it's your actual result to 2dp rounded up. Are you sure your expected result shouldn't be `10.98`?

Comment: no, this type is float, because i set ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES to false. I did an insert of 10.99. But 10.99 != 10.989999771118 or am i wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem as [PHP PDO query returns inaccurate value for FLOAT fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048057/php-pdo-query-returns-inaccurate-value-for-float-fields)

The next time i will use DECIMAL instead of FLOAT.