# Laravel 5.0 PDO Querying float from MySQL gives inaccurate results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-5

To show my problem I made two functions. The first asks Laravel for a PDO instance and queries the database. In the second I instanciate a new one myself.
The first one from Laravel gives inaccurate results. The second one gives the right results.

The table defenition would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `level` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is the first function:

```
public function testpdo1() {
    $pdo = DB::connection('myconnection')->getPdo();        
    $query = "SELECT level FROM event LIMIT 4";
    $result = $pdo->query($query);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        print $row[0] ."\n";
    }
}
```

Which gives these results:

```
102.09999847412
97.900001525879
95.300003051758
94.099998474121
```

This is the second function:

```
public function testpdo2() {
    $pdo = new PDO('dsn', 'user', 'pass');
    $query = "SELECT level FROM event LIMIT 4";
    $result = $pdo->query($query);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        print $row[0] ."\n";
    }
}
```

Which gives these results:

```
102.1
97.9
95.3
94.1
```

The last ones are the correct results.

Is there a way to make Laravel behave like in the second function?

I suppose the difference is in PDO settings. I tried setting PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES but to no avail. I also tried that in the second function to see if I could make the second go wrong. But it didn't work.

Maybe I do something wrong with setting an attribute like that. With laravel (function 1) I tried setting it /config/database.php as an option in my connection:

```
'connections' => [

    'myconnection' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
        'options'   => array (
            PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => true,
        ),
    ],
....
```

With the second function I tried it with

```
$pdo = new PDO('dsn', 'user', 'pass', [PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => true]);
```

and with

```
$pdo->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES , true );
```

after instanciation, with true an false values. It doesn't seem to make any difference...

This question comes close to my question: [PHP PDO query returns inaccurate value for FLOAT fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048057/php-pdo-query-returns-inaccurate-value-for-float-fields)
. But since my second function gives the right answers it seems possible to get the accurate answer.

@Ragu Swaminathan suggests the second function gives rounded values. Just to be clear: those are the values that are in the database.

```
mysql> select level from event LIMIT 4;
+-------+
| level |
+-------+
| 102.1 |
|  97.9 |
|  95.3 |
|  94.1 |
+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I use rounding in the query of function 1 the values become the same as the values from function 2. That is a possible work around but I hope for a better solution.

Comment: actually second function gives you the rounded off results whereas the first gives you the raw values.. But both are seems to be same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why those two functions behave differently is indeed in the PDO settings.
The default for parameter PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES is true.
Laravel sets this parameter to false.

So @Ragu Swaminathan was right. The second function gives me the rounded values. As did mysql_client, phpmyadmin, perl, etc.

I did a few tests with the second function I'd like to share. I changed it a bit.

```
public function testpdo2() {
    $pdo = new PDO('dsn', 'user', 'pass');
    $query = "SELECT level FROM `test`";
    $result = $pdo->query($query);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        print gettype($row[0]).' : '.$row[0]."<br>";
    }
}
```

The result is

```
string : 102.1
string : 97.9
string : 95.3
string : 94.1
```

So I get strings

When I put in this line after instanciating PDO

```
$pdo->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

The result is

```
double : 102.09999847412
double : 97.900001525879
double : 95.300003051758
double : 94.099998474121
```

And when I also(!) add this line

```
$pdo->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES , true );
```

The result is

```
string : 102.09999847412
string : 97.900001525879
string : 95.300003051758
string : 94.099998474121
```

So that is why that didn't seem to help

My last test was an insert of the value 102.09999847412 into the table.
And the "normal" answer came back as 102.1

The conclusion is: floats are not to be trusted.
But we knew that already ;-)